# Laravel 5.2 default auth, how to register when authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to be able to do a post method to the default "/register" from a form even when im already authenticated.

Currently its not possible, I get no errors but I don't get a record in my database.

My form and code works when im not logged in.
Where do i need to make changes so it will work?
I think its near the registersusers.php but that code is completely new to me.

Comment: Can you post some code?  I don't have a fresh copy of Laravel to check the default...The registration controller and routes file should be enough

Comment: If you need to do that (what you ask) and purpose is to register (add another user) you have "bad design". You should consider rethinking.

Comment: its a system where only the owner may register new people when he is logged in. SlateEntropy's solution worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you cannot do this because the guest middleware stops logged in users from accessing the registration page.

In your `AuthController` (provided by Laravel in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth`)  you can specify which methods should remain accessible to non-guests (or authenticated users).

By default only the `logout` method is available to logged in users, however you can add anymore you wish.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => ['logout', 'showRegistrationForm', 'register']]);
}
```

`showRegistrationForm` is responsible for showing the login page and form, `register` is responsible for processing the registration and persisting it.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it's working as intended. A logged in user shouldn't be able to register a user, that doesn't make sense.

However, you can simply use the `RegistersUsers` trait within your own Controller in order to attempt to register a user. It's as simple as this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class RegistrationController extends Controller {
    uses RegistersUsers;

    public function create(Request $request){
        return $this->postRegister($request);
    }
}
```

The `->postRegister()` method is provided by the `RegistersUsers` trait. It accepts an `\Illuminate\Http\Request` object and is injected as a dependency, so you must only pass an instance of `\Illuminate\Http\Request`. You can easily display the `registration` form as well by simply just calling `$this->showRegistrationForm();`, such as this:

```
public function show(){
    return $this->getRegister();
}
```

Now just attach your routes accordingly.